# overlay normal curve over a histogram

Tags: r

I am supposed to draw an overlay normal curve over a histogram in R. I am using the following code.

```
g <- unesco$Infant.Deaths
hist(g)
lines(seq(0, 200, by=5), dnorm(seq(0, 200, by=5),
                                mean(g), sd(g)), col="blue")
```

But instead of a curve, I am getting a straight line
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It can be, that your histogram is representing frequencies instead of probability densities. Try to use `hist(g, freq = FALSE)`.